# Block anonymous folder access with ADFS

Tags: .net, iis, configuration, authorization, adfs

A user authorizes via ADFS to a .net mvc web application. But some special folders are accessible without authorization.

What is the best approach to prevent unauthorized Access to these folders (e.g /bundles)?

Is it possible to make a configuration in the web.config or is it IIS configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to set the special folder's authentication setting.  This setting will just work that folder. Then we could disable the anonymous authentication  for that folder.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IIS manamgement console and select the folder.

[image]

2.Disable the anonymous authentication.

[image]

Comment: I tried the steps you listed and it created a loop, can you help me? (I'm not a networking person) https://serverfault.com/questions/1097299/adfs-access-policies-on-individual-folders

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OWIN middleware for configuring authentication with ADFS then you can secure all anonymous requests with the following code:

```
app.Use((context, cont) =>
            {
                if ((context.Authentication.User != null) && (context.Authentication.User.Identity != null) && (context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
                {
                    return cont();
                }
                else
                {
                    var provider = "ADFS Server";
                    context.Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        RedirectUri = "https://youapp-url/"
                    }, provider);
                    return Task.Delay(0);
                }
            });
```

where app is of type IAppBuilder and provider is AuthenticationType